# Получить путь к заголовку и к контенту с HTML документа

Tags: java, html, java-ee

у нас есть вот такой HTML документ. (HTML получил с первого попавшегося сайта. сайты будут разные)

```
<HTML xmlns:OG="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"xmlns:FB="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<style type="text/css"></style>
<BODY>
<DIV class="block0">
<DIV class="pad0">
<DIV class="fblock">
<DIV class="block61">
<DIV class="rpad"><H1 class="title">ЗАГОЛОВОК СТАТЬИ</H1>
<SPAN class="dt2">Понедельник, 26 сентября 2016, 16:08</SPAN>
<DIV class="text">
<P>Во французском городе Ницца по подозрению в планировании теракта были задержаны двое девушек.</P>
<P>Об этом сообщает <A href="https://www.afp.com">AFP</A>.</P>
<P>Девушки в возрасте 17 и 18 лет подозреваются в планировании террористического нападения под руководством французского 
джихадиста Рашида Кассима.</P>
<P>Подростки рассказали следователям, что они планировали нападение под влиянием Рашида Кассима, который сейчас наход
ится в Сирии или Ираке, на территории, которая контролируется террористической организацией &quot;Исламское государство&quot;.</P>
<P>Рашид Кассим, по мнению следователей, играет роль подстрекателя или спонсора, фактически призывая потенциальных террористов к 
совершению джихада во Франции.</P><P>Стоит добавить, что во время обыска в помещениях, которые принадлежат задержанными, стражи 
порядка не нашли оружия.</P>
<P>Издание отмечает, что девушки живут в том же районе, что и 
<A href="/rus/news/2016/07/15/7052184/">Мохамед Лахуайедж-Бухлель, убивший 86 человек</A> в Ницце 14 июля.</P>
<P>Напомним, недавно французская <A href="/rus/news/2016/09/14/7054550/">полиция задержала подростка</A>, подозреваемого в подготовке теракта
 в Париже.</P>
 </DIV>
 <DIV class="btit4"><SPAN>ЧИТАЙ ТАКЖЕ</SPAN>
 </DIV>
 </DIV>
 </DIV>
 </DIV>
 </DIV>
 </DIV>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

мне нужно получить пусть к заголовку. я пытался записывать этот HTML в документ и делать :

```
String path  = htmldoc.substring(htmldoc.indexOf("<html"),htmldoc.indexOf("title") +7);
```

но это не работает на всех сайтах  и путь после заголовка просто обрезает.
а мне нужно получить вот такой результат -

```
<HTML xmlns:OG="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:FB="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
   <BODY>
      <DIV class="block0">
         <DIV class="pad0">
            <DIV class="fblock">
               <DIV class="block61">
                  <DIV class="rpad">
                     <H1 class="title">ЗАГОЛОВОК СТАТЬИ</H1>
                  </DIV>
               </DIV>
            </DIV>
         </DIV>
      </DIV>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

и такой же путь к контенту статьи.)

может есть какая-то библиотека которая позволяет это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Либами типа Jsoup это делается в одну строку так:

```
String html = ...;
System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(html).getElementsByClass("title").get(0).text());
```

---

Получить путь к найденному элементу можно методом `parent()` как-то так (псевдокод, не проверял, но идея такова):

```
String path = "";
Element target = Jsoup.parse(html).getElementsByClass("title").get(0);
while(target!=null){
    path = path.prepend(target.getName());
    target = target.getParent();
}
```

Comment: Да. достать заголовок это элементарно.
но мне нужно путь к заголовку как в примере вопроса <html><body><div><div>заголовок<div/><div/><body/><html/>

Comment: @ТоликБугера, обновил ответ